# Java HtmlUnit - How to increase the timeout time to load a page?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to load a page which loads by "clicking" on a button like this:

```
page2.getElementById("btn_6").click();
```

The server needs a lot of time to load that page as it needs to do some calculations. The problem I face then is that I get this exception from HtmlUnit:

```
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking submit
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:949)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:878)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2589)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2582)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:173)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.lambda$fireEvent$0(DomElement.java:1475)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1475)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.doClickFireClickEvent(DomElement.java:1143)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1074)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1014)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:910)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:887)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:864)
    at <path to method in "main">(Main.java:80)
    at <path to "main" method>(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking submit
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:254)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:456)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1698)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1013)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventHandler.call(EventHandler.java:70)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:339)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:871)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:934)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2418)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLFormElement.submit(HTMLFormElement.java:340)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:228)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:949)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:192)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1554)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1477)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2409)
    ... 39 more
Enclosed exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking submit
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:254)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:456)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1698)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1013)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventHandler.call(EventHandler.java:70)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:339)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:871)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:934)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:878)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2589)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunction(HtmlPage.java:2582)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:342)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeAtTargetListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:379)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:173)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.lambda$fireEvent$0(DomElement.java:1475)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1475)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.doClickFireClickEvent(DomElement.java:1143)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1074)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:1014)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:910)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:887)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:864)
    at <path to method in "main">(Main.java:80)
    at <path to "main" method>(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2418)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLFormElement.submit(HTMLFormElement.java:340)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:228)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:476)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:470)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:949)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:192)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1554)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1477)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2409)
    ... 39 more
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==
function () {
    [native code]
}
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Is there a way to make HtmlUnit have its timeout set to something like 5 minutes?

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

It's:

```
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(5*60*1000);
```